# Image doesn't show up in gallery after saving the Bitmap in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

after creating a directory in:

> /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ViralFindrr

and saving a bitmap in that directory, the directory and file get created, but it doesn't show up as album in my gallery. Did I miss something?

**Here is my code:**

```
 private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(ImageView imageView, String fileName) {

    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ "/ViralFindrr/");

    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdir();

    File file = new File(dir,System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am testing the code on my android device.

Comment: I am testing on my android device..

Comment: The duplicate is irrelevant, it doesn't answer my question as  it mention something different

Comment: You need to tell your media store to rescan for images. you saved the files correctly but they have not been indexed yet.